# How do I resize a partition in Ubuntu linux without losing data?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition

I ran out of space in my on the drive only to find that there was another unformatted partition in the system that is available. I now want to resize the current partition to take in the empty partition without losing data. Any ideas?

Comment: The eternal reminder of how to *not lose data*...  Make a full and complete backup of your existing partiton **before** you attempt anything of this nature...

Comment: There are some options, but it would help if you gave us your current partition layout.  What is the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` (or whatever your disk's device is called)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

boot from live Linux distro (you can use Ubuntu install disk) and use gparted

But always something can go wrong, so it is advisable to make a `backup`.

The other option is to format the unused partition and mount it and use it (depending on the size) as /home or /usr

Answer (score 2):

LVM is the way to go. Turn your whole spindles into PV's and migrate from legacy partition-based model to LVM model. RedHat has some good documentation on LVM, check it out.

Comment: How does LVM address the issue of not losing data when modifying partitions?

Comment: @fred.bear: LVM makes it a lot less likely that you'll accidentally delete or overwrite a filesystem, because its basic operations are creating a volume on free space and deleting a volume, rather than creating a volume on whatever was there before.

Comment: @Peter.O That's a very complicated solution even if it's a good pratice to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this live CD: [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start)

Answer (score 0):

I've resized my partition successfully without the loss of any data using the method [described here](http://www.stevefortuna.com/resize-ext3-partition-on-vps-live/), which generally is about deleting the current partition and creating a new one with the same start and a greater end.

But that is probably *not the recommended way*, especially when the partition to be resized is in between other partitions, because, in my case I had to remove all my partitions (primary storage and swap) and had to recreate them all.

Answer (score -1):

> to find that there was another unformatted partition

Are you sure that this isn't your swap-partition? Beside from that I would recommend LVM as mentioned before by slashdot.