# Why does X11 on Fedora 16 rely on non-boot device for startup?

Tags: fedora, boot, partition

I have recently had an incident in which my /var/mail/spool/ file grew to the size of 32G (yes, that is gigabytes), completely filling its system partition (/dev/sda2) and most of what I saw inside were Hibernate messages.

When I tried to restart my laptop, I got an error message from the GUI saying that the system was unable to start.  Then I went into the recovery mode (command-line only) and was able to shell into the system.  I did some du investigation and found the above described anomaly.  I deleted the file and then was able to log into X11 (KDE Desktop) fine.

My question is:  Why does X11 on Fedora 16 rely on non-boot device for startup?  Can it be configured to only use the boot device or is X11 considered almost like any other application?  I would like to be able to at least get inside my D.E. even if all other disk partitions are unusable but the boot partition is.

RELATED:

[Disk size management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53230/disk-size-management)

Comment: What partitions do you have? X11 doesn't care about `/boot`, in fact you can run your whole system with `/boot` unmounted. Did you mean the root filesystem instead of the “boot device”? Do you have a separate `/var`? That's hardly ever useful, and a lot of programs do need to write to `/var`.

Comment: /dev/sda1          99150    79569     14461  85% /boot.  i thought all booting business took place there

Comment: `/boot` only contains the bootloader and the kernel. Everything that's done under Linux comes from outside `/boot`. Please edit your question to post all your partitions (output of `df` or of `mount`), you've only posted one that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a filesystem fills up, that can cause all sort of grief. The graphical environment uses space for temporary files in /tmp and /var/tmp, in /var/log the system keeps logs (and if there isn't space it will cause problems). And so on. You should be able to log in in rescue mode (single-user mode, boot with kernel argument 1) and clean up.